# how can i find a key in a map based on a pattern matching in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, pattern-matching

I want to find a key in a map that is similar to a specific text. should I use for loop or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The direct translation of your question is `map.keys.find(_.matches(pattern))` which given a map, gets they keys and finds the first key that matches the regexp pattern.

```
val map = Map("abc" -> 1, "aaa" -> 2, "cba" -> 3)
map.keys.find(_.matches("abc.*"))
// Some(abc)
map.keys.find(_.matches("zyx"))
// None
```

A loop may be counter productive if you don't want to scan all keys.

Answer (score 8):

Suppose you have some regular expression which you wish to match on:

```
val RMatch = """\d+:(\w*)""".r
```

And a function, which takes the matched group for the regex, and the value in the map

```
def f(s: String, v: V): A
```

Then you can match on the regex and collect the value of the function:

```
map collectFirst { case (RMatch(_), v) => f(txt, v) }
```

If you just wanted the value...

```
map collectFirst { case (RMatch(txt), v) => v }
```

**Note**: *the implementation of this method effects a traversal on the map, in case that is not what you were desiring*

Comment: I don't think it works for me: scala> val RMatch = "t".r
RMatch: scala.util.matching.Regex = t

scala> val mymap = Map("two" -> "I", "three" -> "II");
mymap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = Map(t
wo -> I, three -> II)

scala> mymap collectFirst { case (RMatch(_),v) => v}
res12: Option[java.lang.String] = None

scala>

Comment: that's because none of your keys are "t"! try `"t.*".r`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the pattern and the map's underlying implementation.  If the map is a `HashMap`, then it can only give you an exact match against a key, so you can't do anything better than loop over its keys.  If the map is a `SortedMap` and you know the beginning of the text you're looking for, then you can use the `range` method to obtain a part of the map based on the pattern, and loop over that range.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you mean by 'similar to' and 'text'.  If you are using English words you could use the Soundex algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) to give you a code for each word and use that as a hash key, collecting all the words with the same Soundex value together in a list.  If you want to do full text matching then it's a lot more complicated and you need to use techniques such as Inverted Indexes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index).  In that case you'd be best looking at something pre-written such as Apache Lucene (http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) which gives you much more besides simple inverted indexes.  Lucene is written in Java, so it is directly usable from Scala.