# Finding the Value of a Map where the key is a regex

Tags: regex, scala, dictionary

I have a map of (Regex -> Int) and I would like to get the value of the key which will match an entered String.
To explain I have a Map like:

```
(("BR.*".r -> 100),("HA.*".r -> 90),("GE*".r -> 100))
```

How can i get the value 100 when I have a String `"BRUSH"`?

This question seems to be the opposite of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546306/how-can-i-find-a-key-in-a-map-based-on-a-pattern-matching-in-scala)

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to iterate through the map and check every regex key against the string you're trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by iteration over your map and trying to match your input against regex keys:

```
val map = Map("BR.*".r -> 100, "HA.*".r -> 90, "GE*".r -> 100)

map.find(_._1.unapplySeq("BRUSH").isDefined).map(_._2)
```

Result:

```
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[scala.util.matching.Regex,Int] = Map(BR.* -> 100, HA.* -> 90, GE* -> 100)

res0: Option[Int] = Some(100)
```

But note that this approach is inefficient for large number of keys. Consider using special data structures instead, [like trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).